# How to specify a model with multiple treatment groups, measured twice, repeatedly across a time period (lme4)?

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I have 30 animals (factor: `animal_id`, 30 levels) which have been treated with a drug or a vehicle (factor: `treatment`, 2 levels). Their `activity` has then been measured with two sensors (technical replicates) simultaneously (factor: `sensor_id`, 2 levels), yielding 1 reading per sensor for each day, over 30 days (variable `date`). Firstly, should `date` be a factor or a numeric variable?

And the bigger question: how do I specify this design using `lme4`? My main interest is estimating `activity` differences between the two treatment groups, but the values vary heavily across dates so I cannot look at overall effects across all days, so my first attempt is:

```
    lmer(activity ~ treatment*date + (1|animal_id), data=data)
```

Every `animal_id` always has two `activity` values for each `date`, one for each `sensor_id` level. All sensors should ideally be the same, but are expected to have some random differences in sensitivity between themselves, which should be constant, e.g. sensor 1 of animal 28 will be slightly more sensitive than sensor 2 of animal 7 throughout all measurements. So I'm not sure if I should add `sensor_id` somehow. My first thought was to nest it under `animal_id`, changing the random effect term to `(1|animal_id/sensor_id)`, does this make sense even though the differences between each sensor are always constant? I ask, because it sounds to me like the differences between each sensor are "fixed", and this is a "random" effect term. I do not care about estimating the differences between each sensor, though, I just thought it'd make sense to include this in the model as, among the two readings per animal over time, sensor 1's readings will always be more similar to other sensor 1 readings than to sensor 2 readings.

And finally, `activity` can go up or down over the days regardless of `treatment` or `animal_id`. Should this be specified in the model somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, should date be a factor or a numeric variable?

Given how many days you include here, I assume that you have no special interest in any specific day, but the overall trend instead. I think using this as a numeric variable would be okay, so long as there are evenly spaced intervals of time, which here it seems to be the case.

> So I'm not sure if I should add sensor_id somehow. My first thought was to nest it under animal_id, changing the random effect term to (1|animal_id/sensor_id), does this make sense even though the differences between each sensor are always constant?

Since the sensor ID only varies by two levels, you could just add it in as a fixed effect in your model like so:

```
 lmer(activity ~ treatment*date + sensor_id + (1|animal_id), data=data)
```

Since it only has two levels and doesn't seem obvious it would fluctuate systematically by animal, I wouldn't include it as a random slope. This would at least account for the non-independence of this cluster.

> And finally, activity can go up or down over the days regardless of treatment or animal_id. Should this be specified in the model somehow?

Your model already attempts to measure the variation in the response of activity based on fixed and random factors. Random error that cannot be attributed to your model terms is already taken into account, so this isn't necessary to do anything about. That is of course unless you have some other variable in mind which is driving this relationship, which you could of course include.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Regarding the sensor_id as a fixed effect, wouldn't that make the model group sensor_ids across different animals? A problem with that is that when looking across all animals, every sensor is different and sensor_id should have 60 levels (2 levels for every animal_id, which has 30 levels, as there are indeed 60 different sensors in total). I'm sorry, but could I trouble you for a clarification of "fluctuate systematically by animal", specifically, does that mean across animals or within an animal over time? Also, what does non-independence of this cluster mean?

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your original question. I realize there are sensors for each animal, but are the sensors otherwise sharing the same properties for each animal? As an example, a red sensor and a blue sensor for each animal, but these are the only sensors used for all animals?